# Как оптимизировать большой список NOT IN postgres в JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, jpa

У меня есть JpaRepository.
Есть некая сущность Test и бд на postgres в которой больше 10 млн записей.
Мне необходимо обработать все эти записи поочередно.
Для этого есть таблица с id уже обработанных Test.

Я хотел бы получать лист id необработанных Test, для этого, в репозитории я пишу что то такое:

```
@Query("select t.id from Test t " +
        "where t.var is not null " +
        "and ..." +
        "and t.id not in :ids")
Page<Integer> findAllNotGeneratedId(@Param("ids") List<Integer> ids, Pageable pageable);
```

Все работает, но из-за особенностей обработки IN в postgres, он работает очень медленно.
Я прочитал, что можно оптимизировать данный запрос используя вместо "NOT IN" LEFT OUTER JOIN(VALUES ...)  ну и поставив условие.
Я пытался записать это в свой @Query, но он выдает синтаксическую ошибку. В документации JPA не нашел никакой информации по этому поводу.

Как можно реализовать такое? Скажу сразу, что сджойнить исходные таблицы нельзя(свои особенности).
Может быть я вообще думаю не в том ключе? Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1):

тут явно должен быть индекс на поле таблицы, которое определяет "обработанность" записи. если распределение обработанных-необработанных отличается от 50/50, а точнее много обработанных/очень мало не обработанных, то можно даже частичный индекс с условием на необработанные.
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/indexes-partial